# Recursively spawning "child" threads and waiting for their completion without blocking the "parent" thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

Let's say I have tasks `SequentialGroupTask`, `ParallelGroupTask` and `SleepTask`, all inherited from an abstract `Task`. Now I would like to chain them, something like this:

```py
my_task = SequentialGroupTask( # A
            [
              ParallelGroupTask( # B
                [
                  ParallelGroupTask( # C
                    [
                      SleepTask(), # D
                      SleepTask(), # E
                    ]
                  ParallelGroupTask( # F
                    [
                      SleepTask(), # G
                      SleepTask(), # H
                    ]
                  ),
                  SleepTask(), # I
                ]
              ),
              SequentialGroupTask( # J
                [
                  SleepTask(), # K
                  SleepTask(), # L
                ]
              ),
            ]
          )
```

Now I would call `my_task.run()` and as the names suggest, `SequentialGroupTask` would call it's subtask's `run` function one by one while `ParallelGroupTask` would call each function in parallel. `SleepTask` would sleep for some time.

My current implementation:

```py
class SequentialGroupTask(Task):
    ...
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for task in self.tasks:
            task.run(*args, **kwargs)


class ParallelGroupTask(Task):
    ...
    def run(self, queue, *args, **kwargs):
        for task in self.tasks:
            queue.append(task)

class SleepTask(Task):
    ...
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sleep(1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads: dict[int, threading.Thread] = {}
    queue: deque[Task] = deque()
    queue.append(my_task)
    while queue or any([t.is_alive() for t in threads.values()]):
        for i in range(0, max_threads):
            if queue:
                thread = threads.get(i)
                if (not thread) or (not thread.is_alive()):
                    threads[i] = threading.Thread(
                        target=queue.pop().run,
                        name=f"thread_{i}",
                        kwargs={
                            "queue": queue,
                        })
                    threads[i].start()
```

As you can see here, I am using a queue of tasks, looping over it and executing queued tasks once a thread is available.

The problem here is, that `ParallelGroupTask` doesn't wait for it's subtasks to complete. In my example, task A would start task B and then immediately task J without waiting for B.

If I simply waited in `ParallelGroupTask` for all subtasks, I would be blocking a thread which is bad on it's own but also if there were more nested `ParallelGroupTask`s than threads then the n+1 task would be stuck in a queue indefinitely.

I feel like my entire approach is wrong and I'm missing something. Would maybe combining threads with asyncio help somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here is, that ParallelGroupTask doesn't wait for its subtasks to complete.

Correct.

You have exactly identified the sticking point.
We want to `.start()` all tasks in the group,
and then ask `.join()` to block until
all have completed.

Having started a parallel group
of three `sleep(1)` tasks,
we would expect the `.join()`
takes about one second to return.

> If I simply waited ... for all subtasks, I would be blocking a thread which is bad on its own

No, it's not bad at all.
You are yielding the CPU
until those tasks have finished,
plus you are correctly preventing
subsequent statements from executing
until the result data they expect
has become valid.